# node.js fork new server instance for new port

Tags: node.js

Lets assume that we have this server structure:

- load_balancer.js
- server_instance_1.js (port `23101`)
- server_instance_2.js (port `23102`)
- shared_logic.js

For the moment i have 2 server instances as js files that i start manually. The question is - is it possible to automate process of creating and collapsing needed or unused server instance on the fly?

for example i allow 50k connected users for each instance of server, so if my soft will detect that i am coming close to 100k combined it starts new instance on port `23103` while in case that i have 3 instances running and i am going down to around 60k users it shuts down third instance.

If possible (most likely) how it can be achieved?

typical instance code example:

```
var http = require('http'),
    _io = require('socket.io'),
    server = http.createServer();

server.listen('23101', 'IP_ADDR');

var io = _io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // ...

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample 1**: Recursive functions
I managed to achieve this by using a single file to handle the spinning up and shutdown of new servers with some variables to keep track of currently running servers and users.

```
var http = require('http'), _io = require('socket.io');

var servers = [];
var users = 0;
var serversAreClosing = false;

const USERS_PER_SERVER = 50000;

var startServerInstance = function () {
    var server = http.createServer(ports[ports.length-1] + 1); //start a http server on the port after the previous server
    var io = _io.listen(server);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        users++;
        if(users > USERS_PER_SERVER * servers.length) {
            startServerInstance();
        }
    });

    io.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        users--;
        if(users < USERS_PER_SERVER * (servers.length-1) && !serversAreClosing) {
            var lastServer = servers.pop();
            serversAreClosing = true; //Make sure that no other server tries to kill servers if two users disconnect at the same time

            lastServer.http.close(function() {
                lastServer.io.close(function() {
                    serversAreClosing = false;
                });
            }});
        }
    });

    //Put your own code here

    servers.push({"http" : server, "io": io});
}
```

Since i cant see your load_balancer code I dont know how it works, although I imagine you could export the servers variable and then route users to the server with least people connected.

```
var smallestServer;
for(var server of servers) {
    if(!smallestServer) {
        smallestServer = server;
        continue;
    }

    if(smallestServer.io.sockets.clients().length > server.io.sockets.clients().length) {
        smallestServer = server;
    }
}

directToServer(smallestServer); // This should be replaced with whatever code you use to direct users.
```

**Sample 2**: Using `process.fork`

Controller.js

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var forks = [];
var users = 0;
var serversAreClosing = false;
var portAvailable = 23101;

const USERS_PER_SERVER = 50000;

var createFork = function() {
    var newFork = child_process.fork("server.js");
    newFork.send("start", {port: portAvailable});
    portAvailable++;
    forks.push(newFork);

    newFork.on("userConnected", function() {
        users++;
        if(users > USERS_PER_SERVER * forks.length) {
            createFork();
        }
    });

    newFork.on("userDisconnected", function() {
        users--;
        if(users < USERS_PER_SERVER * (forks.length-1) && !serversAreClosing) {
            var lastFork = forks.pop();
            serversAreClosing = true; //Make sure that no other server tries to kill servers if two users disconnect at the same time
            lastFork.send("stop");
            portAvailable--;
        }
    });

    newFork.on("stopped", function() {
        serversAreClosing = false;
    });
}
```

Server.js

```
var http = require('http'),
  _io = require('socket.io'),
  server = http.createServer(),
  io = undefined;

process.on("start", function(port) {
  server.listen(port);

  io = _io.listen(server)
  io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    process.emit("userConnected");
  });

  io.on("disconnect", function(socket) {
    process.emit("userDisconnected");
  });
});

process.on("stop", function() {
  server.close(function() {
      io.close(function() {
        process.emit("stopped");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is quite basic approach, working one for sure, but i am also curious how i can set log file for every instance so then i can analyse data from it, and how well it works when you spin 20 or more instances with 50k capacity each, for sure there are some limits applied on single file memory usage

Comment: You could try this method to increase the memory limit of nodejs http://prestonparry.com/articles/IncreaseNodeJSMemorySize/ although I cant vouch for how well it works.

Comment: thank you that is very accurate resource, i will play with it to explore possibilities, meanwhile maybe someone would contribute with other kind of approach

Comment: If not then you can use `process.fork()` to spin off another nodejs process and then pass in the new port as an argument `process.fork("./serverInstance.js", {execArgv: ["(PortNumber)"]})`

Comment: Could you add to your current answer with example of this in basic way ?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, Not sure if you get notifications for edits but the child_process.fork has been added... The code is merely a proof of concept and will need some heavy poking if you want to get it working in your situation. It wont handle directing users to another server if one is shut down and it wont handle any errors that occur in Server.js.

Comment: While this is the correct answer to your question, I would argue that for a production system you'd be far better off to use a process manager (systemd or pm2, etc) to handle this need. It's going to be more well tested and feature rich for a lot less work than if you try and roll your own.